# How to dynamically generate a new variable in Terraform when using "random" resources (integer/string)?

Tags: terraform

How to dynamically generate a new variable in Terraform when using `random_integer`?

I have the following code in my `main.tf` file.

How can I concatenate `random_integer.ri.result` + `local.project` into a new variable, so I can use the calculated value in other resources?

```
locals {
  project_name = "myproject"
}

resource "random_integer" "ri" {
  min = 10000
  max = 99999
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "default" {
  name     = "rg-${local.project_name}-${random_integer.ri.result}" // <-- avoid this
  location = "eastus"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another `local` like:

```
locals {
  project_name = "myproject",
  random_project_name = "${local.project_name}-${random_integer.ri.result}"
}
```

Or just add the random integer right into the project name like:

```
locals {
  project_name = "myproject-${random_integer.ri.result}"
}
```

Comment: I found that for var + var but didn't occur to me that it would apply to resources. (y)